# How to create a copy of a record that has a timestamp value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, timestamp

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a production table that I need to replicate exactly in another location to work on. I will first run a job to move everything over (once off) and then run a daily job to update the updates/inserts daily.

The daily job will look at the production table and find any new values that need to be inserted (based on a created date) and also find any existing values that need to be updated (based on a modified date). Any new values are inserts and any modified values are updates.

The job pulls these rows from the production table and applies them to the copy table located elsewhere. I am running into trouble with timestamp columns. The production table has a timestamp column and I don't know how I should handle this when updating the copy table (also created as a timestamp column).

I get an error if I set the production.timestamp_col = copytable.timestamp_col (Cannot update a timestamp column).

Should I leave it out (in which case I don't have an exact copy of the table), convert the column in the copy table & the value in the select from the production table to something else (not sure what), put my own value in (again, won't have an exact copy of the table) or drop/truncate and recreate each time (inefficient due to data volumes)?

What would the best approach be in a situation like this?

Thanks

Comment: To copy data on a scheduled base maybe the best solution is replication. That for the `job` you mentioned. Now for timestamp. Think of Timestamp as a GUID for the row. It marks the row uniquely in all the universe ;-) That is the reason that you can have only one timestamp column on a table. So no you cannot have two rows with the same timestamp value. This is useful in some replication scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the destination timestamp column to `varbinary(8)` and then insert the values. This will help you create an exact copy but it will break the timestamp functionality. Do this if you need to have a copy only. The actual purpose of timestamp column is to track changes to a row through versioning.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL a timestamp column is system generated, you cannot update it or set it on insert.  SQL does this all for you.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx

You may be able to pull something off with replication/mirroring to get a 100% exact copy, but it may not be worth it depending on your needs.